# Sending JSON with a POST to server for parsing - why does this ajax call fail?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

So, I send a JSON string to my server for parsing via jQuery ajax. I get the JSON from the Glosbe dictionary's API. Most of the time it works as expected, but there are certain JSONs that fail. What is interesting is that in those cases I get an "Internal server error", but when I tried to debug the application, it seemed like the controller wasn't even called. I don't know how that's even possible.

Here's my View:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Parse", "GetMeaning")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: "ValueToParse=" + jsonToSend, //maybe it's better to send a json instead of a string
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //pass the data to the server for parsing

            //alert("sendJsonToServer successful, sended " + JSON.stringify(json1) + "got back: " + data);
            setMeaningofExpression(expression, data);
            $('#expressionTranslations').html(expressionsAsString());
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('sendJsonToServer error, tried to send ' + JSON.stringify(jsonToSend) + 'problem: ' + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Parse(String ValueToParse)
    {

            return Json(Parser.Parse(ValueToParse).ToArray());

    }
```

An example Json that fails:

```
{"result":"ok","authors":{"1":{"U":"//en.wiktionary.org","id":1,"N":"en.wiktionary.org"},"20":{"U":"//www.slowniki.org.pl/","id":20,"N":"Jerzy Kazojc"},"86":{"U":null,"id":86,"N":"wiki"},"25018":{"U":"//glosbe.com","id":25018,"N":"GlosbeResearch"},"2695":{"U":"//dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2","id":2695,"N":"Wiktionary"}},"dest":"hun","phrase":"cat","tuc":[{"authors":[86],"meaningId":-4164218657921168000,"meanings":[{"text":"member of Felidae","language":"eng"},{"text":"domestic species","language":"eng"},{"text":"A common four-legged animal (Felis silvestris) that is often kept as a household pet.","language":"eng"},{"text":"ket","language":"eng"}],"phrase":{"text":"macska","language":"hun"}},{"authors":[2695],"meaningId":-9072797188187576000,"meanings":[{"text":"domestic species","language":"eng"}],"phrase":{"text":"kandúr","language":"hun"}},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":4566464096976442400,"meanings":[{"text":"domestic species","language":"eng"}],"phrase":{"text":"cica","language":"hun"}},{"authors":[25018],"meaningId":3489096155947903000,"phrase":{"text":"hány","language":"hun"}},{"authors":[25018],"meaningId":-557814434056432960,"phrase":{"text":"krapek","language":"hun"}},{"authors":[20],"meaningId":-2600640194269463000,"phrase":{"text":"muksó","language":"hun"}},{"authors":[25018],"meaningId":-4572067174236314000,"phrase":{"text":"rókázik","language":"hun"}},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"An enthusiast or player of jazz.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(computing) A lsquo;catenate; program and command in Unix that reads one or more files and directs their content to an output device.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(slang, vulgar, African American Vernacular) A vagina; female external genitalia","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(slang) To vomit something.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(Irish, informal) terrible, disastrous.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(archaic, uncountable) The game of ;trap and ball; (also called ;cat and dog;).","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(slang) Any of a variety of earth-moving machines. (from their manufacturer Caterpillar Inc.)","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"raise anchor to cathead","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(nautical) To flog with a cat-o-nine-tails.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"vomit","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(archaic) A sturdy merchant sailing vessel (now only in ;catboat;).","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(slang) Prostitute. [from at least early 15th c.]","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"Any similar animal of the family Felidae, which includes lions, tigers, etc.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(nautical) Contraction of cat-o-nine-tails.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"guy, fellow","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(archaic, uncountable) The trap of the game of ;trap and ball;.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(slang) A person (usually male).","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(nautical) To hoist (the anchor) by its ring so that it hangs at the cathead.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(computing slang) To dump large amounts of data on (an unprepared target) usually with no intention of browsing it carefully.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(derogatory) A spiteful or angry woman. [from earlier 13th c.]","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"A catfish.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"A domesticated subspecies (Felis silvestris catus) of feline animal, commonly kept as a house pet. [from 8th c.]","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(nautical) A strong tackle used to hoist an anchor to the cathead of a ship.","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"(computing) To apply the <b>cat</b> command to (a file).","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"strong tackle used to hoist an anchor to the cathead of a ship","language":"eng"}]},{"authors":[1],"meaningId":null,"meanings":[{"text":"A catamaran.","language":"eng"}]}],"from":"eng"}
```

Comment: I think you should use content type string rather than json or remove content type completely as you are planning to send json as string.

Comment: and do You convert your json  to string before sendindg it?

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with something like this too. Try this:

```
var ValueToSend = {'': jsonToSend };

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Parse", "GetMeaning")',
    data: ValueToSend 
    type: 'POST',
    success:....
```

Notice that I removed `contentType` and `dataType` and that the json string is enclosed in an object with an empty property name. This article helped: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/  Also make sure you have the routing correctly working on the server; I'd recommend leaving the URL hard-coded until you're sure you've got everyting working so I'd replace `url: '@Url.Action("Parse", "GetMeaning")'` with the actual route.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It finds the controller. I know that, because with some JSONs it's working. So I guess there's something in that specific JSON I copied that makes the request fail.

Comment: The json string you posted is valid; try it here: http://jsonlint.com/ Not sure what it could be. I would replace return Json(Parser.Parse(ValueToParse).ToArray()); with something else to see if it works (something hard-coded at first) and I would look into the JsonResult object to see more. Is that a framework type or some custom type you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that ASP.NET blocked the Json because it considered it a security risk because of the `<b></b>` tags.

Comment: ok, cool; not sure where the <b> tag appeared in your question but glad you solved it!

Comment: @frenchie It was in the JSON I tried to send. Thanks for trying to help me!